# Least Squares with Linear Algebra, Can't find the inverse of A^T * A, is there any workaround?

Tags: linear-algebra, regression, least-squares, pseudoinverse

I'm currently creating a program for a class that uses linear algebra to perform linear and non-linear regression. using $\hat{x} = (A^T*A)^{-1}*A^T*Y$. If i have n points, I should be able to find a polynomial that fits those n points of order n-1. For example if I have 4 points I should be able to find a cubic that fits those 4 points.

If I have 4 points, but two of those lie on the same x coordinate, I get:

$A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\1 & 2 & 4 & 8 \\ 1 & 3 & 9 & 27 \\ 1 & 3 & 9 & 27\end{bmatrix}$

If we then multiply this by $A^T$ I get:

$A^TA = \begin{bmatrix} 4 & 9 & 23 & 63 \\ 9 & 23 & 63 & 179 \\ 23 & 63 & 179 & 519 \\ 63 & 179 & 519 & 1523 \end{bmatrix}$

However, you may notice this matrix is singular, meaning I cannot find the inverse I need to perform the regression.

Is there any way around this or will I have to implement a different method of non-linear regression?

Comment: I am not so familiar with this topic exactly, but if you have two points with the same $x$ coordinate but different $y$ coordinates, you are never going to find a polynomial going through both points. Perhaps this explains why the linear algebra breaks down?

Comment: Use Gaussian elimination to solve the normal equations

Comment: @Dylan I tried doing the same regression using the 4 points: (1,1), (2,1), (3,1), (3,2) to find a cubic that fits using desmos and it correctly finds a polynomial with the best $R^2$ value. My program however finds a weird curve and I think the only reason it finds a curve at all is due to floating point error (the shambles of C# but we have to use it)

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Do you mean to find the inverse of the matrix? If so I've already implemented Gauss-Jordan Elimination to find the inverse. If that's not what you mean could you elaborate a bit more or link me an article etc?

Comment: @Novet Why do you need to invert anything?  Just solve the normal equations $A^T A \hat{x} = A^T y$ using Gaussian elimination.  You will obtain infinitely many solutions.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo because the $\hat{x}$ vector contains the coefficients of the curve of best fit equation, therefore I need to solve for it. Unless I am again missing something?

Comment: @Novet You can certainly solve for it.  The problem is that you will obtain infinitely many solutions. There is nothing you can do about that fact other than to accept it. Rethink your aims.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I'm aware I'll get infinitely many solutions, however there is a correct solution as desmos can provide one - clearly this method doesn't deliver that correct solution so I was just looking to see if there was an alteration I could make before trying a different implementation of polynomial regressions.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo "Unit norm solution" doesn't really make sense unless in this context; we can't just scale polynomial coefficients and get an interpolation unless the y-values happen to be 0

Comment: @Novet "I'm aware I'll get infinitely many solutions, however there is a correct solution as desmos can provide one": this is a wild state of affairs. To rephrase, there's this polynomial interpolator that you've found online and you're hoping we can, without interacting with whatever it is that you're working with, guess what the software is doing.

Comment: @Novet That said, I have an educated guess: in the case that there are infinitely many polynomials $f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^d a_ix^i$ that interpolate the given data points (or that come closest to interpolating them in the sense of least squares error), we can choose the solution (among the infinitely many) for which $a_0^2 + \cdots + a_d^2$ is minimized. This least-norm, least-squares solution is guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: @Novet As it so happens, this least-norm, least-squares solution is very conveniently given by $\hat x = A^+ y$, where $A^+$ denotes the [Moore Penrose pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) of $A$. Importantly, $A^+$ is defined even when $A^TA$ is not invertible. In the case that $A^TA$ is invertible, $A^+ = (A^TA)^{-1}A$.

Comment: @Novet Another reasonable solution, I think, is to simply discard any repeated points before finding an interpolating polynomial. In this case, instead of finding a cubic interpolating the values at $x = 1,2,3$, we find a quadratic. This is equivalent to selecting the solution to $A^TA \hat x = y$ for which the leading coefficient of the "cubic" polynomial is zero, or more generally the solution for which the maximal number of leading coefficients are set to zero.